# What is the limit of the following sequence? $\lim_{n\to\infty} 8^\frac{n+1}{3n+2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, infinity

What is the limit of the following sequence?
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 8^\frac{n+1}{3n+2}$$

I substitute infinity in $n$ and I get infinity + 1 = infinity, 3*infinity+2 = infinity. Infinity over infinity = indeterminate.

Thus, would we have: 8^indeterminate (read as: "8 to the indeterminate power")? Looks funny, but actually I don't know another way to think about it, just applying the properties of infinity. Could you explain me what this all mean, please?

Comment: Do the limit of the exponent first as a separate problem. Start that by dividing top and bottom by $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 8^\frac{n+1}{3n+2}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to\infty} 8^\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{3+\frac{2}{n}}$$
$$= 8^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+\frac{1}{n}}{3+\frac{2}{n}}}$$
$$= 8^\frac{1}{3}$$
$$= 2$$

Comment: thank you! I really like your answer! So, in the exponent we apply the following algebraic property, right? a/b = a * 1/b. You jumped a passage, namely, n(1+1/n) at numerator and n(3+2/n) at the denominator. Then we simplify n outside the parenthesis (we might do it in the same passage). I think I even do not need your confirmation...now that I am writing is also clearer...well, thank you!

Comment: Yup I jumped that step....Anyways you're welcome...BTW you can accept my answer if you like it...:-)

Answer (score 3):

As $f(x)=8^x$ is continuous and the sequence tends to $\frac{1}{3}$, the resulting limit is $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L=\lim_{n\to\infty} 8^\frac{n+1}{3n+2}$
$$ln(L)=ln(\lim_{n\to\infty} 8^\frac{n+1}{3n+2})$$
Note that log of the limit is the limit of the logarithm
$$ln(L)=\lim_{n\to\infty} ln(8^\frac{n+1}{3n+2})$$
$$=ln(8)\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n+1}{3n+2}$$
Notice the indeteminate form under the limit, so by L'hopitals Rule,
$$=ln(8)\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{3}$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}ln(8)$$
$$=ln(8^\frac{1}{3})=ln(2)$$
All in all, we get $ln(L)=ln(2)\implies L=2$

Other people have provided good suitable answers as well but i thought this was more mathematical i guess. Hope it helps!

Also note that I used several basic properties of logarithms as well as limits to manipulate the function.